# php push the results to an array by getting from the table

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I have tables like this

```
listing_id 
1
4
345
654

listing documents

listing_id      folder                  filename
000345        full_menu_file            testfile098
000345        header_menu_file          testfile067
000004        full_menu_file            testfile
000001        menu_file                 testfile567
000004        footer_menu_file          testfile76
000004        test_menu_file            testfile65
000345        footer_menu_file          testfile764 
000654        footer_menu_file          testfile098
000654        footer_menu_file          testfile078
```

Now I want to make an array and put those related data in that array. So the final output will be like this

```
array(
    [1] => Array
            (
                [listing_id] => 1
                [full_menu_file] => 
                [header_menu_file] => 
                [menu_file] => 
                [footer_menu_file] => 
                [test_menu_file] => 

            )
    [1] => Array
            (
                [listing_id] => 345
                [full_menu_file] => testfile067
                [header_menu_file] => testfile067
                [menu_file] => 
                [footer_menu_file] => testfile764   
                [test_menu_file] =>

            )

    [2] => Array
            (
                [listing_id] => 4
                [full_menu_file] => testfile
                [header_menu_file] => 
                [menu_file] => 
                [footer_menu_file] => testfile76
                [test_menu_file] => testfile65

            )                           
)
```

So I made my php code like this

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "listings";
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$listing_query = "SELECT * FROM `listings` ORDER BY `listing_id` ASC ";
$cat_array = array();
if( $result = $mysqli->query($listing_query) ) {
    while( $obj = $result->fetch_object() ) {
        $listing_id = $obj->listing_id;

        //Get all the file names
        $get_images_name = "SELECT * FROM `listing_documents` WHERE `listing_id` = ".str_pad($listing_id, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)." ";
        if( $img_query = $mysqli->query($get_images_name) ) {
            while( $object = $img_query->fetch_object() ) {
                if( $object->folder == 'full_menu_file' ) {
                    $full_menu_file_name = $object->filename;
                }
                if( $object->folder == 'header_menu_file' ) {
                    $header_menu_file_name = $object->filename;
                }
                if( $object->folder == 'menu_file' ) {
                    $menu_file_name = $object->filename;
                }
                if( $object->folder == 'footer_menu_file' ) {
                    $footer_menu_file_name = $object->filename;
                }
            }

            $listing_array['listing_id'] = $listing_id;
            $listing_array['full_menu_file_name'] = $object->full_menu_file_name;
            $listing_array['header_menu_file'] = $object->header_menu_file;
            $listing_array['menu_file'] = $object->menu_file;
            $listing_array['footer_menu_file'] = $object->footer_menu_file;

            array_push($cat_array, $listing_array); 

    }
}
print_r($cat_array);
```

But it is not showing the result as I need. So can someone tell me how to do this? Any suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: There's a duplicate key in the array of your second code block. I'm assuming that was unintentional?

Comment: I hope so ... otherwise means listing_id is not the primary key of listing documents and... that will be not fun to go through.

Comment: What output you are getting can you post that?

Comment: _it is not showing the result I need_ -- could you perhaps show us what it **is** showing you?

Comment: Could we have type of listing_id plz - First Str_pad() returns a string we might need an int -

Comment: Your desired output isn't possible. You can't have two `[1]` elements in an array.

Comment: @Falt4rm Since the `listing_id` field has leading zeroes, it must be a string. `INT` never shows up like that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around the result of `str_pad` so it will be treated as a string, not a number with leading zeroes.

```
$get_images_name = "SELECT * FROM `listing_documents` WHERE `listing_id` = '".str_pad($listing_id, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)."' ";
```

You could also combine both queries into a single JOIN:

```
SELECT l.listing_id as l_listing_id, ld.*
FROM listings as l
JOIN listing_documents AS ld ON ld.listing_id = LPAD(l.listing_id, 6, '0')
ORDER BY l_listing_id
```

The equivalent query without a join is:

```
SELECT *
FROM listing_documents
WHERE listing_id IN (SELECT LPAD(listing_id, 6, 0) FROM listings)
ORDER BY listing_id
```

Comment: Could we make that without table joining? As I have some restrictions.

Comment: You can do it with my correction to your original code. But why would you have restrictions against joining?

Comment: If you can't use a `JOIN`, you could select all the listing IDs and use an `IN` which would be better than looping through the results and making many repeated subqueries.

Comment: @Barmar, Or you could use one `MySQL` query which has in itself a subquery, which is the SAME THING as a JOIN, but it doesn't use the JOIN keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the str_pad. You could use CONVERT or CAST instead:

```
SELECT * FROM `listing_documents` WHERE CAST(listing_id AS INT) = $listing_id

SELECT * FROM `listing_documents` WHERE CONVERT(INT, listing_id) = $listing_id
```

Comment: Could we make that without table joining? As I have some restrictions.

Comment: @NewUser This answer doesn't use joining, so what does your question mean?

Comment: A problem with using this method is that it can't take advantage of an index on the `listing_id` column.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema doesn't make sense to me. I don't know why you would use the padded string instead of an integer in your `listing_documents` table. But, using your current schema you could do:

```
$result = $mysqli->query(
<<<'QS'
SELECT listings.listing_id, listing_documents.folder, listing_documents.filename
    FROM listings
    JOIN listing_documents
        ON listing_documents.listing_id LIKE LPAD(CONVERT(listings.listing_id,char),6,'0')
    ORDER BY listings.listing_id ASC
QS;
```

I'm not actually sure if you need to convert the listing_id for lpad. And It probably is more performant to convert `listing_documents.listing_id` to an INT like `ON CONVERT(listing_documents.listing_id,UNSIGNED INTEGER) = listings.listing_id`
Then to add your results to an array:

```
$outputData = array();  
while ($object=$result->fetch_object()){
    if (!isset($outputData[$object->listing_id]))
        $outputData[$object->listing_id] = array();
    $outputData[$object->listing_id][$object->folder] = $object->filename;
}
```

With this approach, if a particular `listing_id` in `listing_documents` does not have all the different `folder`s, then the key would be skipped.

Now, `$outputData` will have the data with array keys being the listing IDs.

To reset the array keys, you could do:

```
$outputData = array_values($outputData);
```

Comment: @Jarkar its showing error like `Notice: Undefined offset` in line `if ($outputData[$object->listing_id]==NULL)`

Comment: Err... That's because I used the wrong thing. I meant to use `isset`. not `==NULL`. I updated my answer.